# Is it possible to read MediaStream asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to figure out how to read the `MediaStream` that is returned from `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to feed it into an `AudioStream` object in the AWS Transcribe SDK. I found code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/fa60bf375c0a142263e4a67a330a79862cfa4102/clients/client-transcribe-streaming/test/index.integ.spec.ts) and tried it out:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
  const AudioStream = (async function* () {
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
      yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: chunk } };
    }
  })();
});
```

When I implement this as one of the params of [TranscribeStreamingClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-transcribe-streaming/index.html), and run it, I get the following error:

```text
Uncaught TypeError: stream is not async iterable
```

Is it possible to iterate MediaStream asynchronously or wrap it in some way (like MediaRecorder or something) that allows it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit late but I started working on the same and found out this question.

Below is the answer.

MediaStream object is not a regular node js type stream which is async iterable. You will have either write your own async generator function - https://javascript.info/async-iterators-generators#real-life-example-paginated-data, where you will capture the chunk and return it or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/microphone-stream npm package which does that for  you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, can you provide a sample code?